# Reverse numerical numbers without use of libraries

Tags: java, reverse

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int number = input.nextInt();

            int reverse = 0;
            while (number != 0)
            {
                reverse = reverse * 10;
                reverse = reverse + number % 10;
                number = number / 10;
            }
            System.out.println(reverse);
       }
   }
}
```

All numbers reverse well but I have problem with reversing numbers that end with zero e.g numbers like `10000` instead of reversing result being `00001` it gives the result as `1` which is not what the question wants is there a way to use integers or string will be the best and easier approach? Thank you

Comment: do the same in the string

Comment: Please elaborate more thank you

Comment: check my answer

Comment: So you’re learning java by having people at stackoverflow doing the exercises for you.

Comment: Did you do the excercise or i posted my code written now that i have a problem i cant ask??

Comment: Reversing a String, which represents a number, is trivial, if you're allowed to use the library method (which you could do for automatic testing of random numbers, which you pass to your method, which would be a good idea anyhow. If you were asked to perform in number land, there is no way to preserve leading zeros. In a number, they vanish. However, you could preserve them as long as possible, by initially multiplying the number by 10, adding a cipher from 1-9, reversing that number and getting rid of the masking digit in the end - but then again, the 1230->12308->80321 will collapse to 321.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the reversing of string concept

```
    String s ="10000";
    String n= "";
    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
      n = s.charAt(i) + n;
    }
    System.out.println(n);
```

Comment: Why might the question be titled "numerical number"?

Comment: since you have to print the output it has nothing to do with whether you use number or string to achieve it and you can not preserve those leading zeros if you work only with integer, you have to use string for that

Comment: Even you find some classes doing that even then you will be using string indirectly. And even if you are on number land it doesnot prevent you to convert number to a string and then use it. It depends on your skills to use the concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable `length`, and use `System.out.printf` to format output.

With `%0 + length + d`, it will add `0` on the left to make the output have this `length`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int number = input.nextInt();

            int reverse = 0;
            int length = String.valueOf(number).length();
            while (number != 0)
            {
                reverse = reverse * 10;
                reverse = reverse + number % 10;
                number = number / 10;
            }
            System.out.printf("%0" + length + "d", reverse);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also solve it with a `StringBuilder`. It already has a method called `reverse`:

```
public String reverseInput(int number) {
    String s = Integer.toString(number);
    return new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();
}
```

You can't have a Integer beginning with `0` except `0` itself. So you will have to work with Strings or other datastructures.

Comment: Why might the question be titled "numerical number"?

Comment: Why didn't you read the question? OP never said he isn't allowed to use Strings!